# How to speed up `npm i` on VSTS/TFS on-premise build agent?

Tags: npm, full-text-search, azure-devops

Is there any way how to speed up `npm i` on VSTS/TFS on-premise build agent? I did find some `npm-cache...` packages, but none works on Windows(according to doc) and all seem like obsolete to me.

I really think the subsequent `npm i` should be fast as hell and not taking minutes. Would switch to `yarn` help?

Comment: Are you doing a clean each time you're running a build?

Comment: Yes, we do "Clean = true", "Clean options = Source Directory". Do you think it might have some impact?

Comment: Yes absolutely. This will also delete your node_modules folder meaning that npm install has to download everything every time.

Comment: You are right! `npm i` went to 2 minutes from 5 minutes.

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek since you can speed up `npm i` by not cleaning the `node_modules` folder, you can write the way as answer and accept it.

Comment: Do you know about tag yarn ?

Comment: Yet Another Resource Negotiator

Answer (score 0):

If you do keep your clean before build approach in place you will eliminate a certain class of build failures where packages aren't declared correctly but they still exist in the project cache on your developers machines. For example, dev adds left-pad, decides to remove it and then goes back to it using it in code without readding to package.json.

You might also take a look at Upstream Sources to see if this helps your situation. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/concepts/feeds/upstream-sources

Comment: Yes, this is very valid point. I think that's why we always do 'clean'. Our workflow is: `Feature branch -> (PR, build1) -> Develop -> (PR, build2) -> Master -> deployment(build2 artifacts) to DEV env -> etc...`. Build1 has to be fast as much as possible, so I think we dont have to do clean there and just build in -`-aot` not `--prod`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `npm ci`which installs out of your `package-lock.json` directly and [speeds up your installs](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171556855892/introducing-npm-ci-for-faster-more-reliable).

Answer (score -1):

Disabling `clean` in build definition definitely speed up the `npm i` step, but be aware of @MotoWilliams answer.